# VoIP socket on iOS 16 and Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, pjsip

I am developing an app which uses PJSIP library to maintain an open VoIP socket. Since updating to Xcode 14 and my device to iOS 16, the app crashes upon launch when trying to connect the VoIP socket. The crash log says the following:

> Application Specific Information:
> Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push
> Connectivity instead

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Yoni Did you solve this issue? Some issue I am getting the same issue. can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Apple seems to be enforcing their deprecation of VoIP sockets.

You can keep PJSIP from using them by declaring

```
#define PJ_IPHONE_OS_HAS_MULTITASKING_SUPPORT 0
```

in your config_site.h before you compile pjsip. It is described [here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Commonproblems) too.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `pj_activesock_enable_iphone_os_bg(PJ_FALSE)` before creating any sip transport.